# convergence of a general series bounded above

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, formal-proofs

A series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ converges if the sequence $s_{n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k}$ converges. Suppose that $a_{n} \geq 0$ for all $n\geq 1$. Prove the following are all equivalent:

(i) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ converges.

(ii) the sequence $s_{n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k}$ is bounded above.

(iii) for all $\epsilon >0$, there is an $N$ such that $\sum_{k=N+1}^{m} a_{k} < \epsilon$ for all $m > N$.

Edit: So here’s what I’ve done so far:

$\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space$
Assume statement $(i)$ is true. Let $\epsilon=1>0$, let $s_{n}= \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k}$, and let $L = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$. Then by

the definition of a limit, since the
sum converges, $\exists N, n\geq N \Rightarrow |s_{n}-L| < \epsilon = 1$. Thus, we have

$-1 < s_{n} - L < 1$. By the triangle inequality, $|s_{n} -L| \geq |s_{n}| - |L|$. Since

$a_{n} \geq 0 \forall n \geq 1$, $L \geq 0 \Rightarrow |L| = L$. Thus,
$|s_{n}| -L \leq |s_{n}-L| < \epsilon=1 \Rightarrow |s_{n}| < L + 1$. Let

$R = 1+ max\{L+1, s_{1},s_{2}, ..., s_{n}\}$. Then $s_{n} < R \space \forall n\geq 1$, so the sequence is bounded above (i.e.

statement $(i) \Rightarrow$ statement $(ii)$).

$\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space$
Assume $s_{n}= \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k}$ converges. By the limit definition, we have that

$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists N, \forall n \geq N, |s_{n}-L| = |\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k} - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k}| =  |\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} a_{k}| = \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} a_{k} <\epsilon$ (the last

step uses the fact that $a_{n} \geq 0 \space \forall n\geq 1$). But since $\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} a_{k} > \sum_{k= n+1}^{m}a_{k}$, where $m> n \geq N$,

we have that statement $(i) \Rightarrow$ statement $(iii)$.

$\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space$
Now assume statement $(iii)$ is true. Since for all $\epsilon >0$, there is an $N$ such that

$\forall m >N \sum_{k=N+1}^{m} a_{k} < \epsilon \space \Rightarrow s_{N} +\sum_{k=N+1}^{m} a_{k} < s_{N} + \epsilon \space$. But this means that

$ \forall \epsilon >0, L = s_{N} + \sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty} a_{k} < s_{N} + \epsilon$. Since $a_{n} \geq 0\forall n\geq1, s_{N} \leq s_{n} \forall n \geq N$. So we have that

$\forall \epsilon >0, \forall n \geq N (L = s_{N} + \sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty} a_{k} < s_{N} + \epsilon \leq s_{n} + \epsilon)$. Rearranging the equation gives

$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists N, \forall n \geq N \space(L - s_{n} = |L -s_{n}| = |s_{n}-L| < \epsilon)$, which satisfies the definition of a

limit and so statement $(iii) \Rightarrow$ statement $(i)$, creating a loop. Thus, the statements are all equivalent.

I’m not sure if I’m missing something. Any help would be very much appreciated!!!

Comment: Can you show us what you have done and where you got stuck?

Comment: If I followed correctly, you proved i -> ii, i->iii and iii ->ii. You need to prove that ii implies either i or iii to conclude equivalence. It should be easy using the hint I gave you and some property about monotonic and bounded sequences.

Comment: @nicomezi, I'm pretty sure I proved i-> ii, i->iii, and iii->i.

Comment: But ii implying something is still missing.

Comment: I'm too lazy to correct it since this post is old and I don't have time, but if since $a_n\geq 0 \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$, $s_n$ is monotone increasing. Since it is bounded above, by the monotone convergence theorem, it has a limit, so ii -> i, as you said in your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints :**

i) -> iii) : $s_n$ converges, then it is a Cauchy sequence.

ii) -> i) : what can you say about the variations of $s_n$ ?

iii) -> ii) : Let $\epsilon = 1$, what can you deduce ?